# Do I have to make a backup of my files, when I change OS?

Tags: installation, 12.10, windows-7

I´m at a turning point .. to change my OS from W7 to Ubuntu.

The thing is: *Do I need to make a backup of my files?*

Or, can I just *install* the **new** OS and my files will ALL be quite safe?

Comment: It's always good to have a backup, in case you want your files to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few checks that you should seek:

1. Do you have a HDD which is completely partitioned into Windows
   (NTFS) partitions?
2. Do you want to completely remove windows on
   your computer and install Ubuntu?

In case both the answers to the above questions are yes, take a backup.

Answer (score 0):

***Simple Answer.***

**YES. All your files will be overwritten, by the new installation of *Ubuntu***.

---

***Suggestion:***

- (First) Backup all your documents, media, settings (email, passwords) to a USB device **or** external HDD.
- Install **Ubuntu** alongside Windows 7, and see if it works (for you).
- (OPTIONAL) (Much Later) You can remove / replace Windows 7 with **Ubuntu**.

Comment: Look good, I'll delete my now-useless comment :)